# Transition to ViewController Tapping a TableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

How would one go about making a transition to a view controller by tapping on a table view cell? My current structure is:

I use a `navigation controller` as my only way of navigating through my app atm. 
I use `view models` of type `struct` to represent individual cells. These view models conform to a custom protocol, which consists of a method I call `cellSelected`.

**My question is then:** 
 How can I transition to a `view controller` by tapping on a cell using my `cellSelected` function? Is this possible?

Custom protocol:

```
protocol CellRepresentable
{
    var reuseIdentier: String { get }

    func registerCell(tableView: UITableView)
    func cellInstance(of tableView: UITableView, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    func cellSelected()
}
```

Example of a view model:

```
struct ProfileNameViewModel
{
}

extension ProfileNameViewModel: TextPresentable
{
    var text: String
    {
        return "Name"
    }
}

extension ProfileNameViewModel: CellRepresentable
{
    var reuseIdentier: String
    {
        get
        {
            return ProfileTableViewCell<ProfileNameViewModel>.reuseIdentifier
        }
    }

    func registerCell(tableView: UITableView)
    {
        tableView.register(ProfileTableViewCell<ProfileNameViewModel>.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: ProfileTableViewCell<ProfileNameViewModel>.reuseIdentifier)
    }

    func cellInstance(of tableView: UITableView, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentier, for: indexPath) as! ProfileTableViewCell<ProfileNameViewModel>
        cell.configure(withDelegate: self)

        return cell
    }

    func cellSelected()
    {
        // ?? 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the tableView delegate method `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a couple of options, you can either pass a reference of your navigation controller to the view model, or you can define a closure that gets executed on `cellSelected`.

**Option 1:**

```
struct ProfileNameViewModel {

    private let navigationController: UINavigationController

    init(withNavigationController navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.navigationController = navigationController
    }

    func cellSelected() {
        navigationController.pushViewController(...)
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
struct ProfileNameViewModel {

    private let selectedAction: () -> Void

    init(withSelectedAction selectedAction: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.selectedAction = selectedAction
    }

    func cellSelected() {
        selectedAction()
    }
}
```

and on your view controller:

```
let vm = ProfileNameViewModel(withSelectedAction: { [weak self] in
    self?.navigationContoller?.pushViewController(...)
})
```

Comment: Would it be a bad idea to simply just change the function signature of `cellSelected()` to instead return a `UIViewController` instance and push to that view controller from the `main controller` that handles stuff with the `view models` and cells? Something like `func cellSelected() -> UIViewController`

Comment: I think that if I went with that approach (the one I suggested), it would restrict the generality of the protocol. I like both of your options. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Actually.. I just realized that since I am using MVVM, this method is not an option for me. I guess I did not explicitly state that I am using MVVM. At least not option 1, I guess.

Comment: In my opinion it makes sense for the View Model to handle the transition to the next controller (better yet, delegating it to a Router or similar). I guess it depends on what you understand should be the responsibilities of the View Model and the View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

1- Go to Storyboard click on your viewController and in the Utility Area which is on the left side of xcode, and give it a storyboard identifier.

2- go back to you code and execute this in cellSelected()

let say your viewController is called MusicListVC

```
    func cellSelected() {

        if let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "your Identifier") as? MusicListVC
        {

            navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController , animated: true)
        }
}
```

Comment: cellSelected method is not inside a view controller class, so you can't access navigationController here.

Comment: Your example seems to be specific to the use of Storyboard. I am writing the application programmatically without the use of Storyboard.